# In simics, what is the command to print virtual to physical memory map?

Tags: memory-mapping, x86-emulation, simics

When debugging a kernel running on the simics-x86-core-i7-x58-ich10 target, how to print the physical memory map?
`memory-map` seems to print only the physical memory space mapping for objects (ram, apic, vga, etc.).

`l2p` print the mapping for a specific logical address, not for all the mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cpu0.tlb.[core_number][thread_number].status` or `cpu1.tlb.[core_number][thread_number].status`, etc.